# Using Multiple Threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I've been trying to understand how multi-threading work so i ran the below code:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package mainBowl;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Kbluue
 */
public class ThreadStudy {

Thread t, t1, t2;
Runnable r, r1, r2;

public ThreadStudy() {
    init();
}


public void start(){

}

private void init(){
    t = new Thread(r);
    t.setName("Thread");
    t1 = new Thread(r1);
    t1.setName("Thread 1");
    t2 = new Thread(r2);
    t2.setName("Thread 2");

    r = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
           // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
            if (t != null){
                printStart(t);
                try {
                    Thread.currentThread().wait();
                } catch (Exception e){
                    printError(t);
                }
                printResume(t);
                t1.notify();
            }
        }
    };
    r1 = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
           // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
            if (t != null){
                printStart(t1);
                try {
                    t1.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ThreadStudy.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                printResume(t1);
                t2.notify();
            }
        }
    };
    r2 = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
           // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
            if (t != null){
                printStart(t2);
                t.notify();
                printResume(t2);
            }
        }
    };
}

private void printStart(Thread t){
    System.out.println("This is a new thread starting" + t.getName());
}

private void printResume(Thread t){
    System.out.println("This is a thread resuming" + t.getName());
}
private void printError(Thread t){
    System.out.println("There is an error" + t.getName());
}

public void run(){
    t.start();
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
}
```

}

and then i ran this in the main activity

```
new ThreadStudy().run;
```

but the output gave nothing. just;

```
run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

not even an error message to work with.

Also I'd like to know if there are more ways to add commands/methods to a thread other than the new Thread(Runnable r) method.
Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Java concurrency is a **massive** topic. There are literally hundreds of ways to create threads and assign tasks to them. This question is far too broad. What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: First initialize the `Runnable` objects then initialize the `Threads` .It will work as expected.

Comment: Also *add the runnables to the threads*. Right now you are adding null values to the thread (Braj pointed out why.)

Comment: In addition, `wait` and `notify` are not directly related to the `Thread` class: You can `wait` on any java object.

Comment: But you should not wait or notify a Thread object.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and avoid confusion by never naming your non Runnable class methods 'run'

Comment: @BoristheSpider i want all three threads to run all at the same. with each pausing and calling for another to continue in it's place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's worth reading here [Oracle Java Tutorial - Defining and Starting a Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html)

An application that creates an instance of Thread must provide the code that will run in that thread. There are two ways to do this:

- *Provide a Runnable object*. The Runnable interface defines a single method, run, meant to contain the code executed in the thread. The Runnable object is passed to the Thread constructor.
- *Subclass Thread*. The Thread class itself implements Runnable, though its run method does nothing. An application can subclass Thread, providing its own implementation of run.

---

You can do it without using `Runnable` interface by simply overriding default `run()` method of `Thread` class

Sample code:

```
t = new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
       // add your logic here
       // or call any method from here
    }
};
```

Comment: 'In addition, wait and notify are not directly related to the Thread class: You can wait on any java object' how do i further interact with other threads using wait() and notify()?

Comment: Given the diversity of the concurrency API, overriding run of thread is, generally, discouraged...just saying ;)

Answer (score 3):

You're passing your Runnable variables to the Thread constructor before they are initialized. When the thread starts it will delegate to its own `run` method which does nothing.

Remember that java is pass by value.

Comment: but `Runnable` objects are initialized before calling `start` on the Threads. It's the same reference in the memory. Isn't it?

Comment: @braj They passed, for ex., `r` to the constructor. It had a value of `null`. That's what the `Thread` object stores as its `Runnable`. That doesn't change if `r` is reassigned to something else.

Comment: so this logic is done in the Thread construction itself.

Comment: @Braj Yes, `Thread` keeps a reference to a `Runnable`. If it is null, it executes its own `run` method, otherwise it executes that `Runnable`'s method.

Comment: how do i define "its own run method, " ?

Comment: @kb You didn't actually add any runnable to your thread. You added null. Initialize your variables before using them.

Comment: but as you can see in the code, i used a command that wouldn't run if my thread is null and that will be the case if i don't initialize my thread first. how do i go around that?

Comment: @kbl You misunderstand. Your threads aren't null. They are referencing null runnables. When that happens a thread uses its own run method which does nothing.

Comment: @Kb Remember `Thread` implements `Runnable`.